# Why is my crystal oscillator not working with KSZ8999 switch?

Tags: switches, oscillator, crystal

I am using KSZ8999 ethernet switch from Micrel and I have problem with 25 MHz external oscillator. There is constant 2,1 VDC on output pin which is VDD for the switch, so crystal is not oscillating.
There should be no problem with crystal, because I tried to connect it to other design and it worked fine. I also tried using different values of load capacitors but with no result. There is also no short circuit between VDD and crystal pin.
Can you please help me find out, what could cause this problem? Thank you for your answers.

[image]

R15 is now 510k, R16 is 0R, C41 and C42 is 15p. Crystal MPN is now GC2500081. Sorry for the weird schematic symbol, it was downloaded this way.

Comment: Instead of commenting on your own question, use **Edit** to add that remark to the question. *There is constant 2,1 VDC on output pin which is VDD for the switch, so crystal is not oscillating* What output pin, output pin of what? Why do you think that the 2.1 V DC is incorrect? How did you measure it? How do you conclude that the oscillator isn't working? Maybe the KSZ8999 chip is damaged?

Comment: Crystal oscillators are highly sensitive to loading, and even just putting an oscilloscope probe on one can make it stop oscillating entirely. Are you sure that isn't the problem here?

Comment: To clarify: what I'm suggesting is that it's possible your crystal _is_ oscillating, but it stops when you try to measure it due to the loading effect of the scope probe.

Comment: Output pin of KSZ8999 - X2, which is connected to crystal. X1 is input pin for switch and there is constant voltage 0 V. The value 2,1 V isn't incorrect but the fact that it is constant and not oscillating. I measured it with digital oscilloscope. When i connected one probe to GND and second probe to crystal, it shows either 2,1 V or 0 V (depending on, which pin of crystal I am connecting to). I have two identical PCBs with this switch so I assume there is some systematical problem, because crystals are not oscillating on any of them.

Comment: When I connected this crystal to other design, I had no problem to see it oscillating with the same probe. Of coure probe is set to X10.

Comment: "Of course probe is set to X10"  Why?
And without any schematic its hard to tell anything.

Comment: Many oscillators like this self-bias (data sheet yields little help here). Others require a bias resistor from XO to XI pin, often 1 Megohm. XI & XO pin should measure about the same voltage: near half the supply Vdd.

Comment: You state "*...There should be no problem with crystal, because I tried to connect it to other design*". What is this other design?

Comment: @glen_geek The reference design schematic shows a DC bias resistor of 500k across the crystal. Design guide at http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/KS8999_V1.2_DP.zip

Comment: Also: *I have two identical PCBs with this switch so I assume there is some systematical problem* That's a tough statement unless **you** designed the PCBs with the Switch IC. Did you design these PCBs? What does the circuit look like?

Comment: Before you place _any_ chip on your board, you _really_ need to look at the schematics of the eval board so that you know how to use this for your application.

Comment: @Eggi 1:10 probe is to lower the capacitance, I added schematic to the post

Comment: @glen_geek Yes, I should measure about half Vdd, but I measure full Vdd (2,1 V).

Comment: @PeterSmith STM32 kit NUCLEO-F767ZI, I replaced my crystal with X4 on this board which is also 25 MHz and my crystal worked fine there, so it is not broken.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes, I designed this board. I just added circuit with crystal to the topic. Do you need the whole schematic? Mostly KSZ8999 eval board was my reference.

Comment: @MMA3 If an external bias resistor doesn't yield half-Vdd voltage at the oscillator output, one looks for other faults: a 25 MHz logic signal applied into pin 176 (X1, clock input) should yield an inverted 25 MHz signal on pin 177 (X2, clock output). If not, your oscillator is toast, or there is a pcb board fault.

Answer (score 2):

In the clip below from the reference design schematic in the [demo board user guide](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/KS8999-1180926.pdf), there is a 500K [bias resistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce_oscillator) across the crystal.

To fix the problem, you can probably solder an 0201 resistor across the package pins or a larger resistor across the crystal.

[image]

Comment: This is certainly a *very* common reason for crystals not oscillating.

Comment: Looks like a third party seller (Mouser) from that link you provided. From Microchip's website about their [eval board](https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/KSZ8999-EVAL) it has different decoupling capacitor values with 18pF in lieu of 22pF. There was apparently a revision in 2007 that changed those capacitor values.

Comment: I just added part of my schematic to the topic. I replaced 2M2 resistor with 510k, 22R with 0R and 27p capacitors with 15p (sadly I don't have 18p) but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard for us to troubleshoot this with very little information.

Assuming you are correctly measuring the output pin with low enough loading, there are several possibilities.

- The crystal could be defective or incompatible with the chip
- The load capacitors could be grossly wrong value (eval board uses
  18pF implying their  crystal is designed for maybe 12-16pF load).
- There could be some issue with leakage (unlikely, but possible) or
  PCB construction (open, short, bad via etc.)  that is preventing the oscillator from working. Shorts under SMT crystals are a possibility. If the leakage was comparable to the bias resistor then it might not start. As crj11 says, you need the bias resistor (some ICs have it internal, this one does not).
- The IC could be damaged

I would start by removing the crystal and load capacitors and replacing the crystal (and load caps) with a different one with compatible load capacitance of a similar level to the eval board, having a good look at the (cleaned) PCB under a microscope prior to re-assembly. Also make sure the solder and flux being used is appropriate. SMT capacitors are unmarked so checking the value with a meter prior to installation wouldn't hurt. Mistakes happen and an 18nF capacitor looks similar to an 18pF capacitor (usually the body is a bit darker in colour). Double check the bias resistor value as crj11 says, if it is too low (or too high) the oscillator will not work.

Pierce oscillator (from [this](https://abracon.com/uploads/resources/PierceOscillator_Fundamentals.pdf) document:

[image]

Comment: Since this crystal worked fine on other design, I conclude that it is not damaged. What do you mean "incompatible with the chip"? How could it be incompatible? I tried more values of load capacitors (15p, 27p, 33p) but nothing changed. I also checked connection between chip and crystal with multimeter and it is fine. I have two identical PCBs so I assume that both ICs aren't damaged. Just to mention, this is my design, I'm not repairing someone elses PCB.

Comment: Because it worked before is not really a strong recommendation. It could have been marginal and there is some small change in chip parameters (eg. gm = transconductance of the on-chip amplifier) from batch to batch. This is a pet peeve of mine, there is really no guarantee that this type of oscillator will actually work, especially starting at temperature extremes. Suggest you try another brand of crystal, or even an HC-49 type, after checking other items. Also if it worked and then stopped, make sure you are not overdriving the crystal.

Comment: P.S. It's a higher confidence if you've produced many batches, of reasonable size, and have done thorough testing of many (or all) units including starting at temperature extremes in an environmental chamber.

Answer (score 0):

Even that I didn't want to believe it, truth is that both switches are probably damaged. I measured only 50 and 130 ohms on these chips respectively between X1 and GND which is much lower resistance that it should be. I measured same resistance even when I disconnected pin from PCB, so the problem is inside IC.
Anyway thank you all for your advices.

Comment: That’s unfortunate. I wonder if the ESD protection is less effective on the crystal connections.